# Magento 2 - 404 files not found

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento2.2

I try to made some changes in Magento blank theme, after the modifications was done I use this command:

```
 rm -rf pub/static var/cache var/composer_home var/generation var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed
```

and then I use this:

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f    
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now in frontend and in backend too I have errors like this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/css/custom-style.css"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/css/styles-l.css"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/css/print.css"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/css/styles-m.css"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/requirejs/require.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/mage/calendar.css"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exapmple.com/pub/static/version1508058582/frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB/requirejs-config.js"
```

What was wrong or what I need to do? and much more than this from where or what is **version1508058582**

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the logs It looks like you are using `en_GB` locale , so please try to generate static content deploy for this locale

```
php bin/magento s:s:d en_GB  -f
```

and version `1508058582` is random number generated by Magento after generating static content. So If you execute this command magento generate new number for it. and most Importantly do not forgot to clear cache,

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```